# $(".rowchange tr:even").addClass("even") in more than one table

Tags: jquery

I'm using this nice litte jQuery Scritp to change the class of table-rows:

```
$(".rowchange tr:even").addClass("even");
```

But when I use more than one table on the same page the result can be like this:

```
<table class="rowchange">  
<tr class="even"><td>...</td></tr>  
<tr><td>...</td></tr>   
<tr class="even"><td>...</td></tr>  
</table>  
...
<table class="rowchange">
<tr><td>...</td></tr>
<tr class="even"><td>...</td></tr>
<tr><td>...</td></tr>
</table>
```

How can I get it work, that the all tables start with `<tr class="even">` ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to iterate over each `table` and apply that script separately to each one:

```
$(".rowchange").each(function () {
    $(this).find("tr:even").addClass("even");
});
```

This is because the `:even` selector is being applied to all elements in the matched set, and that will be all `tr` elements that are descendants of `.rowchange` elements. It won't take into account differences between those ancestor `.rowchange` elements.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/EbaMY/9/).

Comment: @Dirty-flow - How does that show it not working? That is the desired effect as far as I can tell from the question. (The tables are treated independently rather than all `tr` elements being treated in one block)

Comment: oops sorry, this works. The three points between both tables maked it look false. My mistake

Comment: @Dirty-flow - Ahh, yeah I can see how that would be confusing. I'll add an updated link to my answer.

Comment: yes, it works perfect :-)  
Many thanx for that instant help!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `table` as main selector and `find()` your ordering will be correct.

```
$('table.rowchange').find('tr:even').addClass("even");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also select it with this selector:

```
$(".rowchange").find("tr:even").addClass("even");
```

Here is an [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/EbaMY/10/)